# Which SQL operation will give me the product of two tuples?

Tags: sql-server

Refresh my memory. I can't recall how to join tuples (a,b) and (c) to produce (a,b)*(c). For example:

```
n
---
0
1
2
```

And

```
site_id     value
----------- -------------
1           a
1           b
2           c
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
site_id     value          n
----------- -------------- -- 
1           a              0
1           a              1
1           a              2 
1           b              0
1           b              1
1           b              2
2           c              0
2           c              1
2           c              2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a [CROSS JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx), also known as the Cartesian product.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```

You can also do it without the JOIN keyword just by using a comma:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2
```

Here's full test code you can use to verify that it works:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (n int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Table1 (n) VALUES
(0),
(1),
(2);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (site_id int NOT NULL, value nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Table2 (site_id, value) VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(2, 'c');

SELECT Table2.site_id, Table2.value, Table1.n FROM Table1, Table2
```

Results:

```
site_id  value  n
      1      a  0
      1      a  1
      1      a  2
      1      b  0
      1      b  1
      1      b  2
      2      c  0
      2      c  1
      2      c  2
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me every possible combination. For example (2,a,1) was contained in the results. I want ((a,b),c).

Comment: OK. I posted some test code, but I guess you don't need it now. Never mind!

Comment: I'd never use the "comma" notation here for clarity, and since SQL Server 2005 in compatibility mode 90 this syntax is deprecated for outer joins anyways and the explicit JOIN syntax is always preferred! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do a CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Select *
FROM table1, table2
```